# TLS 1.2 connection with lftp

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, ssl-certificate, ftps, lftp

I'm trying to connect to a server from my RHEL 7 server that only accepts FTPS, TLS 1.2 connections.  The only client available seems to be lftp.  When I try to connect, it hangs on "TLS negotiation...".  I have it in debug mode, but it still doesn't provide any further info.

Here's my ~/.lftp/rc file:

```
set ssl:ca-file "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
set ssl:cert-file "/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem"
set ftp:use-feat false
set ssl:priority "NORMAL:-SSL3.0:-TLS1.0:-TLS1.1:+TLS1.2"

set ssl:check-hostname false
set ssl:verify-certificate no
debug
```

I added this to the /etc/lftp.conf file:

```
set ftp:ssl-force true
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

-Scott

Comment: did you end up solving this?